Cant terminate task in R taskscheduler
Started a task in taskscheduler in R, used taskscheduler_stop to terminate, retuned  'SUCCESS: The scheduled task "Hello-World-Schedule" has been terminated successfully'. [1] 0, but task is still running (shows up in taskscheduler_ls). Is there any other way to end this task (it runs every minute)?
taskscheduler_stop(taskname), expecting termination

Welcome to SO, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, then edit your post so folks can give relevant feedback

I think you may be confused about what the functions are doing.
From the docs:
?taskcheduler_stop


Stop the run of a specific task which is running in the Windows task scheduler.

?taskscheduler_ls


Get all the tasks which are currently scheduled at the Windows task scheduler.

So your call to taskcheduler_stop() stopped the current run of your task. However, the task is still scheduled to start again in Task Scheduler and therefore continues to show up in calls to taskscheduler_ls().
Perhaps you are interested in taskscheduler_delete(). This would remove your task from the output of taskscheduler_ls().

Delete a specific task which was scheduled in the Windows task scheduler.

Or maybe you are interested in disabling the task, but because {taskscheduleR} does not have a function for that, you will need to implement your own.
It might look something like this:
taskscheduler_disable <- function (taskname) {
  cmd <- sprintf(
    "schtasks /change /TN %s /DISABLE", 
    shQuote(taskname, type = "cmd")
  )
  system(cmd, intern = FALSE)
}

